# 3 posts in one row, and then one post

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to have 3 blog posts appear in one row all next to each other, and then the next row only has one blog post, the next 3 in a row, and so on.  I have figured out how to get 3 posts and then 1, but for the 3 posts there are only 2 posts in a row and the third post is put on the next line.  I have tried expanding the width of my blog, but that did not work.  Does anyone have any solutions?

Here is my index.php file

```html
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: learningwordpress
 */
 
get_header();
 
$i = 0;
 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 7,
    'paged' => 1
);
 
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
 
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
 
        if( $i %2 == 1 ) {
            $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-12">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('large-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>
            <?php
        }
        else {
            $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-6">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>      
            <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-6">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>
 <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-6">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
}
else {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading the code correctly, your grid has 12 columns (based on the single row being `col-md-12`).  To split that into 3 columns per row, you need `col-md-4`, not `col-md-6` for your article classes.

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to accept my answer (hit the check mark beside it) and/or upvote - that's how we say thanks around here :)